# How to update html table without disturbing scroll position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**HTML:**

```
<div class="html_table"></div> # In html body tag.
```

Ajax function to get table data.

```
var $html_table= $('.html_table');
function ajaxCallFunction() { $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(res, status, xhr){
                $html_table.html(res['html_table']);              
            },
            error:function(xhr, status, error){
            }
          });
```

Updating table for every 5 seconds,

```
    window.onload = function() {            
      ajaxCallFunction();

    setInterval(ajaxCallFunction, 1000*5);
}
```

**Issue:**

I have 100 rows in a table. Need to update it every 5 seconds without disturbing the position of scroll. When the user looking to the bottom line, the scroll bar goes to its original position after 5 seconds. How to handle the issue?

How to update the cell value of the table, without affecting the scroll position?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

**Note:**

In my case, its more important that focus on current row should not get affected.

Comment: Updating your table every 5 seconds doesn't seem to be the best idea. Why not listen to changes instead? Also, if table changes, do you want the scroll to be at the exact same position? (which won't obligatory correspond to the same row if there was changes)

Comment: @Kaddath Can you please suggest links *Why not listen to changes instead?* Or you can post as answer. In my case, its more important that focus on current row should not get affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current scroll position before changing the html and restore it after you changed the html.

```
var savedScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop;
```

in response callback then restore the position:

```
$(window).scrollTop(savedScrollPosition);
```

If the requested HTML is different from the previous one this is of course not working. Maybe you could calculate the real new scroll position relative to the height of the old and new HTML and the saved scroll position in such a case.